# menuitem not getting disabled in c# project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a menuitem which should be disabled by default. and when a particular button(Stop Button) is clicked in output screen it should be enabled. I have tried using IsEnabled property but its not working, menuitem is not getting disabled. Am I missing anything? Need Help please!

.xaml

```xml
<MenuItem Header="Save Trace"  
          IsChecked="{Binding 
          SavingTrace,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          IsEnabled="{Binding Config.StopButtonEnable}">
</MenuItem>
```

.cs code

```cs
bool stopButtonEnable;
public bool StopButtonEnable  
{
    get
    {
        return stopButtonEnable;
    }
    set
    {
        stopButtonEnable = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("StopButtonEnable");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from binding to a nested object. Instead of calling `RaisePropertyChanged("StopButtonEnable")` in your nested object's setter, you should call `RaisePropertyChanged("Config")` where you set StopButtonEnable's value.

For example:

```
private void ToggleMenuItem()
        {
            Config.StopButtonEnable = !Config.StopButtonEnable;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Config");
        }
```

This should update your binding.

Answer (score 0):

The other possibility is to define `StopButtonEnable` as a dependency property:

```
public bool StopButtonEnable
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(StopButtonEnableProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StopButtonEnableProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty StopButtonEnableProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("StopButtonEnable", typeof(bool), typeof(ConfigClass), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

When registering the dependency property fill the *ownerType* with the correct type of your `Config` object (I've named it `ConfigClass` for the time being).
When defining the binding in the XAML file you can set the mode to *OneWay* (this way it's stated that your menu item is not altering the dependency property)